# What's the difference between a=[1] and [1] in python?

Tags: python, list

When I do

```
a = [1]
a.append(2)
print a
```

the result is `[1,2]` - but the result of

```
print [1].append(2)
```

is `None`.

My understanding is that `a` is the reference of list object `[1]`. Everything in python is object. `[1]` is also a list object. `a` and `[1]` should be exactly the same.
Why the result is totally different?

Comment: Try printing `print a.append(2)`

Comment: If you had done `print a.append(2)`, you would have seen `None` as well. You changed too much between the two experiments.

Comment: If you're learning Python, don't bother with old Python 2 when Python 3 is available and stable by now.

Comment: better try print a+[2] or print [1]+[2]. append return None

Comment: Why doesn't the implementation of append function return the list object ? Is it good to return a None? I believe that a=[]; a.append(1).append(2); this style is better for me to accept.

Comment: By design, `list.append` doesn't _return_ anything.  The coding style is called [command-query separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation).  There are only a few situations in which you want a single operation to both alter something _and_ return something, typically an atomic transaction of some sort: removing an item from a collection (while keeping a reference to that item), inserting an item into a location-aware data structure, making a "payment" in exchange for a "receipt" of some sort, etc.

Comment: Since I didn't make it clear in my previous comment:  Notice that, in all the examples I gave, what's returned from the mutator is _not_ what was given to it.  They all return some new, related information that the caller _didn't_ already know.  Drawing a card from a shuffled deck mutates the deck (which you already had), and gives you the top card (which you didn't know).  Inserting a job into a location-aware priority queue returns the job's _location_ in the queue (determined when the item is inserted), which you will need if you ever want to change that job's priority.

Answer (score 4):

You have misunderstood your code. The difference has nothing to do with the variable; it is that in the second you are printing the return value from `append`, but append *always* returns None. If you printed `a.append(2)` in your first code you would *also* get None, except that `a` would have been modified in the meantime.

Answer (score 4):

The `None` is the result of the method call on `list.append`. `append` modifies the list in place and does not return a new list. So you basically have appended `2` to `[1]`, but as you never stored the list you don't get to see the result.

The fact that `append` does not return a value (other than `None`) is a hint already that the method is side-effecting (in this case mutating its argument).

If you want to return a new object each time you append to a list you should use `+` instead:

```
a = [1]
a + [2]
>>> [1, 2]
```

The value of `a` will not have changed now:

```
a
>>> [1]
```

You can chain this arbitrarily

```
a + [2] + [3,4] + [5]
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Why doesn't the implementation of append function return the list object ? Is it good to return a None? I believe that a=[]; a.append(1).append(2); this style is better for me to accept.

The reason is if python support chainable. Everything in python is an object.       Like this, print [1,2,3].append(4).append(5). It is very easy to use and don't even need to name the [1,2,3] object.

Comment: @dong You may use `+` instead of `append` for that. E.g. `a + [1] + [2]` will return `[1, 2]` (assuming `a` was the empty list). `append` is specifically for mutation, while `+` will return a new object. `append` not having a return value (i.e. having the return value `None`) indicates, that it's a fully side-effecting method.

Comment: @dong:  Returning a reference to a mutated argument is _guaranteed_ to be useless --- the caller already _has_ that reference, because that's how the caller passed it to the function in the first place.  In fact, returning it is downright dangerous, because it makes a mutator 's signature indistinguishable from an accessor's:  Does `props = properties.set(other_props)` _set_ a bunch of properties, or just return a _copy_ of the given properties as a set?  This is the kind of land mine that command-query separation exists to prevent.

Answer (score 3):

In

```
print [1].append(2)
```

you are printing the result of the `list.append` method, which is `None`.

Answer (score 3):

In your first example, you are appending 2 to the list `[1]` and then print the list, the output is as expected.

In the second example you print the **return value** of `[1].append(2)`. What happens here is that you print the return value of `append`, which is `None`.

However, if you had a reference to your list, you could check that it is now modified. This little demo should make clear what happens:

```
>>> a = [1]
>>> print a.append(2) # This will print None
None
>>> a
[1, 2]
```